# hourly weather data: create daily difference from MAX and first measurement

Tags: r, weather

I am doing snow-related research and have hourly data of snow height.

I want to create a variable expressing positive snow-height change over a day, which is best approximated by calculating the difference between the MAX value and the first measurement on that day.

The next best solution I have come up with is calculating the difference between MAX and MIN by extracting MAX and MIN using summaryBY - the code looks like this:

```
snowheight_change<-summaryBy(data=sh_hourly, snowheight ~ date,  FUN=c(max, min), na.rm=TRUE)
```

But it's not as accurate, is there a way to also extract the first of the 24 hourly measurements using `summaryBy`?

Comment: can you please provide a data-sample. Then it becomes much easier to help you

Comment: @Sebastian Fischer  Any info about the `date` will be helpful.  Is it just `%Y-%m-%d` or include the time?  Also, info about the data is ordered by 24 hour time interval for each day or not would be helpful.

Comment: I'm quite new to R and stackoverflow - so I'm afraid this is going to raise more questions: what's the best way of exporting the data sample from R (it's been processed quite a bit with R) and providing it on stackoverflow?

Comment: @akrun date does include time and is ordered

Comment: @Sebastian Fischer If the `date time` is one column, then it would be better to change it into date only format for grouping.  Check my update.

Comment: @Sebastian Fisher Update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
set.seed(49)
sh_hourly <-  data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2008-02-04"), length.out=40, by='1 hour'), snowheight=sample(1:25,40,replace=TRUE)) 
library(data.table)
setDT(sh_hourly)[, date1:= as.Date(date)][,
                    list(snowheight=max(snowheight)-snowheight[1]), by=date1]
 #        date1 snowheight
 #1: 2008-02-04         15
 #2: 2008-02-05         12
```

#### Update

```
 library(doBy)
```

Using the previous dataset `sh_hourly` which is not converted to `data.table`

```
 sh_hourly$date1 <- as.Date(sh_hourly$date)
 res <- summaryBy(data=sh_hourly, snowheight ~ date1, FUN=max)
 res[,2] <- res[,2]-sh_hourly$snowheight[firstobs(~date1, sh_hourly)]
 res
 #       date1 snowheight.max
 #1 2008-02-04             15
 #2 2008-02-05             12
```

Comment: Thank you so much, code works! I reloaded the original data and processed into the format you generated in sh_hourly to make it work (since I am new to R and need to learn a lot about the language it uses). But just for the record, there is no FUN in summaryBy that could extract the first measurement of the day from the hourly measurements?